# private statement Java

Tags: java, singleton, private

I am super new to Java programming. Here is a confusion I have.

```
public class Singleton
{
public static Singleton GetInstance()
{
if (sInstance == null)
{
sInstance = new Singleton();
}
return sInstance;
}
private Singleton()
{
// No code here
}
private static Singleton sInstance;
}
```

I am wondering what does the last `private static Singleton sInstance` do? Don't you want to declare it at the beginning of the code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it makes you really happy, you can put it in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sInstance is Object that you want to return by GetInstance(). If sInstance == null (so it wasn't created yet) new object is created, if not same object as created before is returned. Singleton type sInstance object is private so only public GetInstance() method can return it (the only public access method in Singleton Class). This design pattern won't let you create more than one instance of Singleton object reffered by sInstance. Like Manouti said in previous response, it doesn't matter where you put it on your code, but at the beginning it's just more readable.

Answer (score 1):

`sInstance` is a class member field that is declared as `static`. It is of the same type as the enclosing class `Singleton`. And the compiler accepts it whether at the beginning or at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in case of static fields and instance level methods because the static fields are resolved and initialized during *class loading and Initialization* phases. So instance level methods already know about the *existence* of the static field when they are accessed.

Try doing the same thing (accessing before declaring)for static blocks / sattic fields and instance blocks/ instance fields gives errors

```
static{
    if (i == 0) { // error . i cannot be resolved
        System.out.println("0");
    }

}
static int i;

{
    if (i == 0) { // error . i cannot be resolved
        System.out.println("0");
    }

}
int i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because sInstance is a static variable means you can access this no matter the placement in the code. Placing it at the beginning of the code is more readable but either way works.